# Getting rid of white space/ new line characters from the first element(string) of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The problem is, right now, as a result of function I am getting this on.

```
"\n    inventory:\n-devices:\n      platformtypes:\n    "
```

But my purpose is to get

```
 "inventory:\n-devices:\n platformtypes:"
```

This is what I am doing,

```
function searchStringInText(text, str) {
    for (let i = 0; i < text.split("\n").length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < text.split("\n").length; j++) {
        if (text.split("\n")[j].includes(str)) {
          return (
            [text.split("\n")[j],
            text.split("\n")[j + 1],
            text.split("\n")[j + 2]].join("\n"));
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So, basically, all i need is by calling searchStringInText(text, "lesson") to get from this text

```
const text ="explore: true
moon: -932373914.9990492
pot: -505393312.24021673
lesson: true
cut:
  - next
  - - false
    - white
    - true
    - true
    - 1835506785
    - false
  - -1526841500
  - 1191695591.8601308
  - 2062118801.9208922
  - title
shorter: out"
```

I need to get

const newText=

```
lesson: true
        cut:
          - next
```

So, there is a need to return new text started from a founded occurence, and including next 2 lines.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to manually parse yaml?

Comment: i want to return a new text starting from a string I pass as a parameter. In my case , the call would be `searchStringInText(text, "lesson")`

Comment: @lan, how do you want the output from the search you input? you input ```lesson```, then how do we know you stop at ```- next``` ?

Comment: From your comment: ```i need to return only 3 lines of text started from founded occurence``` , but do you want to remove the inner space of each line  in your output as well? or just trim the line?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)?

```js
const text =`explore: true
moon: -932373914.9990492
pot: -505393312.24021673
lesson: true
cut:
  - next
  - - false
    - white
    - true
    - true
    - 1835506785
    - false
  - -1526841500
  - 1191695591.8601308
  - 2062118801.9208922
  - title
shorter: out`;
function getPosition(string, subString, index) {
  return string.split(subString, index).join(subString).length;
}
const startIdx = text.search('lesson');
const stopIdx = startIdx + getPosition(text.substring(startIdx), '\n', 3);
const result = text.substring(startIdx, stopIdx);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the problem is, i need to return only 3 lines of text started from founded occurence

Comment: I updated the answer to only include three lines

Answer (score 1):

From your comment: `i need to return only 3 lines of text started from founded occurence`

Update: I change it to one line and faster performance.

**Example Below**

```js
const text = `explore: true
moon: -932373914.9990492
pot: -505393312.24021673
lesson: true
cut:
  - next
  - - false
    - white
    - true
    - true
    - 1835506785
    - false
  - -1526841500
  - 1191695591.8601308
  - 2062118801.9208922
  - title
shorter: out`;

function getString(text, search) {
  return text
    .slice(text.indexOf(search))
    .split("\n")
    .slice(0, 3) //slice the first 3 lines
    .map(obj => obj.replace(/\s/g, "")) //replace all the inner space
    .join("\n");
}

console.log(getString(text, "lesson"));
```